# How to download .vcf file from an joomla 2.5 article?

Tags: php

I am Having an joomla article which contains name, email id, contact no in it.
And I want to download it as a vcard or as an vcf file.
Is it possible to download vcf file from an joomla 2.5 article

Comment: Anything is possible. That said try to come up with a programming question anyone could help you with. But searching the web for Joomla plugins is your homework.

Answer (score 0):

Joomlas "Contact" component already contains functionality to manage contacts and download contact details as vCards. You can link to that contact in your article. vCard functionality must be enabled in Components->Contact and then Options-Button as this is hidden by default.